# Did Einstein say this quote about blind belief in authority being the "greatest enemy of the truth"?

Tags: quotes, albert-einstein

There is a [quote/image circulating Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/sayerjigmi/photos/a.280104922151139/1625301110964840/) (please don't get me started on the source), quoting Einstein:

> Blind belief in authority is the greatest enemy of truth

I would like to avoid getting into the validity of the quote in the context its been used, rather I don't believe that Einstein did in fact say that quote to begin with. (I have found the quote on [Good Reads, but it's not cited](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/10610-blind-belief-in-authority-is-the-greatest-enemy-of-truth)).

**Did Einstein say "Blind belief in authority is the greatest enemy of truth"?**

If so, where/when?

Comment: As it is said to be from Einstein, I blindly  believe it ...

Comment: for anyone looking for validation for spreading coronavirus (you know they're reading this), I'll point out that **blind disbelief in authority is the second-greatest enemy of truth**.

Answer (score 71):

[The Ultimate Quotable Einstein](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Ultimate_Quotable_Einstein/A32-DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=authority%20enemy%20of%20truth) has this quote:

> > Blind obedience to authority is the greatest enemy of the truth.
>
> To Swiss teacher Jost Winteler, with whom he boarded while attending school in Aarau, complaining about a professor who would accept no criticism, July 8, 1901. CPAE, Vol. 1 Doc 115

This is very close to what you have in the question. The difference in wording may be due to translation.

Answer (score 49):

Too long for a comment below Laurel's answer, so I'm posting this as a separate answer but I'm really amending Laurel's answer.

The last part of the two stated versions is the same. For the first part, it seems that Einstein used the term "Autoritätsdusel" (https://books.google.de/books?id=NbbzAUehU50C&pg=PA65#v=onepage&q=autorit%C3%A4tsdusel&f=false): "Autoritätsdusel ist der größte Feind der Wahrheit." Everything after "Autoritätsdusel" is straight-forward to translate. The only ambiguity here is the translation of "größte" which only refers to the size or magnitude of a things, whereas "greatest" can also mean *superb* or *magnificent*. However, I think that its meaning in this context is pretty obvious. The other words all are clear-cut translations of the German words and there is no grammatical ambiguity either.

Regarding "Autoritätsdusel": "Autorität" obviously means "authority". ["Dusel"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dusel) has two pretty different meanings. One of them is having good luck in an unjustified fashion. This is not what we're looking for. The other meaning is much more difficult to translate but goes into the direction of being unaware of what's happening in one's immediate surroundings. This is closer to blind belief than it is to blind obedience as there is no part of the original quote that suggest anything about obedience. Note that authority is not necessarily something that tells people what to do. An authority might simply issue opinions.

Minor note: Einstein did not talk about an authority in the sense of a government agency. The German word "Autorität" does not have this meaning.

I am a native German speaker.

Comment: non-german speaker, mostly ignorant on any translation, so please take with a grain of salt - the de.wikipedia page for Autorität uses *either* a person or an institution in opening definition. Is their a difference in translation of the word institution that would exclude a government agency? Not to say Einstein would have used it in that way, and obviously in the cited source he's referencing an academic - but does the word *always* exclude government?

Comment: @TCooper No, there term does not exclude government at all. In English, the term "authority" can refer a government agency's power to enforce rules, give orders, or have other influence. This is just the same with "Autorität" in German. However, revenue-generating government agencies are referred to as *authorities* in the English language. This is not the case in German.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for clearing that up (+1 btw, great addition for the other answer)

Comment: So dusel and düssel are different words, I take it?

Comment: @Accumulation "Düssel" is a distributary of the Rhine, while "dusel" colloquially describes unexpected or even unmerited luck, besides the meaning given in the answer. They are pronounced differently and I can't see how one word would be an alternative spelling for the other.

Comment: Perhaps worth giving the full original quote: “Autoritätsdusel ist der größte Feind der Wahrheit.” (from the source linked in this answer).  The part “…is the greatest enemy of [the] truth” is pretty straightforward to translate — the literal translation has pretty much the same connotations as the original, as far as I’m aware (native English speaker, moderate German competence).

Comment: So if I understand your points, we could better translate Einstein's statement as "*Blind(unquestioning?) belief in authority is the greatest enemy of truth.*"  spoken in the context of academia and/or science.  Given that Einstein *was* a scientist it may also be worth noting that this is pretty consistent with the philosophy of science itself.

Comment: @TCooper Seeing the quote in context, the authority referred to was not that of a government in power, but that of renowned scientists/experts ([argument from authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority)). Given that Einstein's theories overthrow Newton (as Newton overthrew Aristotle), this fits well. Of course, with Einstein's biography, the political interpretation would fit just as well

Comment: A nice answer. Not sure if you can separate "blind belief" and "blind obedience" (although they are different things in most scenarios I can think of they will be interconnected) but I get why you do it since in this case Einstein seems to talk about "knowledge" not "actions".

Comment: Native German speaker here. "Dusel", as noted above, can mean something like "luck" or "fluke". It can also mean something like "daze" or "befuddlement". To say, "ich bin ein wenig duselig heute" means something like "I feel a bit dizzy today". So, "Autoritätsdusel" probably means something along the lines of "letting somebody's authority or renown cloud your own reasoning".

Comment: Now you need to realise that this quote is from Einstein, so if an “authority” in physics says X and Einstein says “Y”, the authority is likely wrong. You are not Einstein.